# Why won't --uts=private allow me to set the hostname?

Tags: hostname, namespace, podman

If I launch a container `--uts=private`, I still can't change the hostname. But it sounds like this is exactly what this is supposed to be for?

What does `--uts=private` do?

```
$ podman run -ti --uts=private alpine
/ # hostname foo.bar.baz
hostname: sethostname: Operation not permitted
```

The error is slightly different with CentOS,

```
$ podman run -ti --uts=private centos:7
[root@e5fd4d09f5c3 /]# hostname foo.bar.baz
hostname: you must be root to change the host name
```

If my container has a new private namespace, why can't I change the hostname?

Answer (score 3):

We are blocking you based on Namespaced Capabilities.
By default containers do not get CAP_SYS_ADMIN.

```
$   podman run -ti --uts=private --hostname foobar centos
# hostname
foobar
```

```
$   podman run -ti --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --uts=private  centos
[root@a4f36e700ad7 /]# hostname foobar
[root@a4f36e700ad7 /]# hostname
foobar
[root@a4f36e700ad7 /]# exit
```

Comment: why is the ability to set the hostname locked behind cap_sys_admin? Why is `sethostname` in that bundle, rather than allowed by all with a private uts namespace?

Comment: @EvanCarroll I don't know how that `podman` sofware works, but it looks like you're terribly confused wrt. Linux namespaces -- they don't give you any extra privileges. A process running in a separate uts namespace still needs to be root (= cap_sys_admin) in order to change its separate hostname.

Comment: @rhatdan For reference, this is why I found this confusing. If jump into a namespace, you can do things you couldn't otherwise do like create files with uid=0, gid=0. Inside that namespace I have this capability. I don't need to grant CAP_SYS_FS_ROOT or anything to do it. It seems like I should be able to change the hostname in a UTS namespace for just the same reason. It's my personal view of the hostname. The API here, however accepted seems very unintuitive. I know now that I need UTS capabilities, but I'm not sure why if I own the namespace they're needed.

Comment: By extension, I also wonder if it's any _less_ save to grant the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` permission when the container has a private namespace. Is there *any* drawback outside to this that the special capability even exists for?

Answer (score 1):

From irc.freenode.net/#podman,

> < nalind> EvanCarroll: unless you run the container with `--cap-add sys_admin`, the default seccomp filter (from `/usr/share/containers/seccomp.json`) will not allow the `sethostname` syscall, and the kernel will disallow the call anyway

I would like to know a lot more than this, but it's a start. So i'll mark it as a community wiki, and delete it when there is a real answer.

Namely,

- what purpose is a private uts namespace if you can't set the hostname?
- why is the ability to set the hostname locked behind `cap_sys_admin`?